# how to get model from collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the next script:

```
var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var GamesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Game
});

var games = new GamesCollection();

var portal = new Game({name: 'Tetris', year: '2017'});
games.add(portal);

console.log(games.get(0));
```

Why does "games.get(0)" return 'undefined'?
May be I use get method not in correct way?

Answer (score 8):

Short and sweet, you need:

```
games.at(0)
```

`.get` is for attributes.

Answer (score 5):

AFAICT `get()` on models is for attributes, but in your case you are dealing with a collection, which means `get()` is:

"Get a model from a collection, specified by id."

E.g.

```
collection.get(1); // Get model with id = 1 from collection
```

Because you haven't supplied an id when you made the new Tetris Game, Backbone will generate one on its own, which is likely not "0".

However in your case `at(index)` seems to have been the one you looked for, my answer was just to clearify things.

E.g.

```
collection.at(0); // Get model at collection index 0
```

Comment: This is the most accurate answer. The other one as it is, misses the very important point that collections also have a `.get(id)` function.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I am unable to figure out how to call a method on the returned model. I assumed I could do something like:

`collection.at(0).methodName();`

But it's undefined. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Figured it out. It actually was working correctly, the method itself just wasn't returning anything so when I logged it I would get 'undefined', which I took to mean it wasn't finding the method. It just wasn't getting anything back _from_ the method.